# PySide: Creating a list of checkboxes

Tags: python, checkbox, pyqt, pyside, qgridlayout

I'm trying to create a list of checkboxes in PySide. 
These checkboxes will reside within a grid which is inside of a frame.

Because I need over a hundred checkboxes, I thought it would be best to store these checkboxes in a list.
Within `class Ui_MainWindow(object):` there is `def setupUi(self, MainWindow):` and within that I'm calling my method `myChanges` with `self.myChanges(MainWindow, self.customCheckBoxes, self.frame, self.gridLayout)`. Right above that I create an empty list to try to store the objects in with `self.customCheckBoxes = []`

Outside of the `Ui_MainWindow` class, I have a separate class named `CreateCheckbox` which tries to make a checkbox under a frame, set the object's name, add it to a spot in the grid and set it's text. From what I can tell, it can execute the first two perfectly fine, the problem arrises with the line `self.grid.addWidget(self.checkBox, gridPlace, 1, 1, 1)`. More specifically, it has a problem with `grid` and throws this error: `AttributeError: 'CreateCheckbox' object has no attribute 'grid'`

My questions are:

1. Am I using grid in the wrong way?
2. Am i not allowed to use dots around grid when I pass it in?
3. How do I fix this problem so the checkboxes all go down a single file line down the grid?
4. Is my `CreateCheckbox` class or my `myChanges` method in the wrong place / where would I put them instead?

Edit: I think I found what I did wrong. in `class CreateCheckbox`, there should be no `self.` in `self.grid.addWidget(self.checkBox, gridPlace, 1, 1, 1)` because the grid is not an instance of the `CreateCheckbox` class

Edit 2: Just in case anyone wants to get the text working, put quotes around `MainWindow` in 
`self.checkBox.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate(MainWindow, text, None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))` so you have 
`self.checkBox.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", text, None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))`

Here's the full code:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def myChanges(self, MainWindow, checkboxes, frame, grid):
        for j in range(100):
            checkboxes.append(CreateCheckbox(MainWindow, frame, grid, "Test", j))

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.frame = QtGui.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 90, 371, 311))
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.frame)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        # Create list holding checkbox objects
        self.customCheckBoxes = []
        self.myChanges(MainWindow, self.customCheckBoxes, self.frame, self.gridLayout)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))


class CreateCheckbox(object):
    def __init__(self, MainWindow, frame, grid, text, gridPlace):
        # 1. Create under appropriate frame
        self.checkBox = QtGui.QCheckBox(frame)
        # 2. Set its name
        #    Although the designer does this, pretty sure this is unneccesary
        self.checkBox.setObjectName(chr(gridPlace))
        # 3. Add it to the appropriate spot in the grid
        self.grid.addWidget(self.checkBox, gridPlace, 1, 1, 1)
        # 4. Set text that user sees
        # For now, I'm just sending 'Test'
        self.checkBox.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate(MainWindow, text, None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that CreateCheckbox has no member named grid.

I think that you meant to reference the `grid` variable that you passed into the class constructor (`__init__`)

```
class CreateCheckbox(object):
    def __init__(self, MainWindow, frame, grid, text, gridPlace):
        #################
        self.grid = grid
        #################

        # 1. Create under appropriate frame
        self.checkBox = QtGui.QCheckBox(frame)
        # 2. Set its name
        #    Although the designer does this, pretty sure this is unneccesary
        self.checkBox.setObjectName(chr(gridPlace))
        # 3. Add it to the appropriate spot in the grid
        self.grid.addWidget(self.checkBox, gridPlace, 1, 1, 1)
        # 4. Set text that user sees
        # For now, I'm just sending 'Test'
        self.checkBox.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate(MainWindow, text, None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

Comment: Yup, you're right. Is there any reason for me to do 'self.grid = grid' instead of grid.addWidget... etc?

Comment: Yes, if you intend to reference the grid object anywhere outside of `CreateCheckbox.__init__`.

Answer (score 1):

This code leads me to believe that you expect `CreateCheckBox` to return a `QCheckBox` object but that's not what you are doing.

```
def myChanges(self, MainWindow, checkboxes, frame, grid):
    for j in range(100):
        checkboxes.append(CreateCheckbox(MainWindow, frame, grid, "Test", j))
```

CreateCheckbox should either be a function that returns a QCheckBox object or a class that derives from QCheckBox.

```
def CreateCheckbox(MainWindow, frame, grid, text, gridPlace):
        # 1. Create under appropriate frame
        checkBox = QtGui.QCheckBox(frame)
        # 2. Set its name
        #    Although the designer does this, pretty sure this is unneccesary
        checkBox.setObjectName(chr(gridPlace))
        # 3. Add it to the appropriate spot in the grid
        grid.addWidget(checkBox, gridPlace, 1, 1, 1)
        # 4. Set text that user sees
        # For now, I'm just sending 'Test'
        checkBox.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate(MainWindow, text, None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        return checkBox
```

Or you can make CreateCheckbox a method:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def CreateCheckbox(self, MainWindow, frame, grid, text, gridPlace):
        # 1. Create under appropriate frame
        checkBox = QtGui.QCheckBox(frame)
        # 2. Set its name
        #    Although the designer does this, pretty sure this is unneccesary
        checkBox.setObjectName(chr(gridPlace))
        # 3. Add it to the appropriate spot in the grid
        grid.addWidget(checkBox, gridPlace, 1, 1, 1)
        # 4. Set text that user sees
        # For now, I'm just sending 'Test'
        checkBox.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate(MainWindow, text, None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        return checkBox
```

Comment: You're right, I completely forgot about returning the checkbox